# mysql.proc keeps crashing, cannot do a mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysqldump, crash

Due to some problems with InnoDB, I'm going to dump all databases to a new server:

```
mysqldump -E -R --all-databases | pv -b | mysql -u root -p -h new.server
```

The dump process stopped with error:

```
59.9kB assword: 59.9kB 
ERROR 145 (HY000) at line 2970: Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and should 
    be repaired
 228MB 
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

I've ran the following command to repair all tables in all databases:

```
mysqlcheck --auto-repair --all-databases
```

When I examine the `mysql.proc` status, I get:

```
mysql> check table mysql.proc;
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table      | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| mysql.proc | check | status   | OK       |
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

However, I still get the same error when re-running the `mysqldump` command.

I have approximately 2000 store procedures. Can that be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

> ERROR 145 (HY000) at line 2970: Table './mysql/proc' is marked as crashed and should 
>       be repaired
>    228MB 
>   mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

... suggests that the problem is writing not reading, so do a repair on the destination database.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem, this was fixed by issuing a command, assuming mysql data dir is on /var/lib/mysql/mysql

**myisamchk -q -r /var/lib/mysql/mysql/proc**

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html